# My tittle on SERP do not exact match with my tittle tag

Tags: seo, google, wordpress, search-results

Can anyone here help me about my title problem in google?

My title in google result page do not exact match with my title tag. If you search with keyword "itclax furidacchi" in google, my title there is a anime word. Im not use anime word in my title. I dont know what must i do again, i inspect element doesnt work, nothing anime word in my element site.!

[image]

NB: one of author make my question is duplicated, but i cannont resolve my problem with read duplicate post.

Comment: The the search term `itclax furidacchi` only returns two links in `google.com`. Searching on just `furidacchi` as you have in the screenshot doesn't return the same results. The second link is `Drama Percosplayan Mbak Furidacchi - IT-CLAX` without `Anime` in it. As you'll see in the answers in the linked questions, you can't really control what Google will return. It depends on what they think the searcher might want to see, and from where they are searching from. Other than considering the length, the content might come from your page, search terms, or previously associated keywords.

Comment: Due to these different uncontrollable variables, we mark questions as a duplicate of the first one linked above, as the other links above have been too. Please note that we don't do [individual site reviews](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here either - questions have to be generic and not only applicable to your site so that it's helpful to others in the future.